# developing a site in drupal made a mess in modules .. is there better way?

Tags: 7, database

When I develop a site in Drupal, I test a couple of modules to see what best suits my needs. The problem is that, if it is a large site, I find myself with a lot of modules and patches (disabled / uninstalled), which still exist in the modules folder. There are a lot of modules that don't have an uninstall feature; the result is that I get many unused tables in the database, and many used files to delete.

Is there a better solution, or way to proceed for testing modules?

Comment: If a module doesn't clean up after itself, that's a bug. Please file an issue in the appropriate issue queue.

Answer (score 3):

You can of course create a test site to experiment with certain modules and patches before adding them to the real site.

Version control is also really helpful, because it allows you to revert to a previous version of your code. However you need to keep in mind that your database is not under version control, so you need to take a snapshot of that as well to do a proper rollback.

A more advanced solution is to use [drush make](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) and the [features module](http://drupal.org/project/features). The features module allows you to store a lot of configuration in code. When combined with drush make, it allows you to roll out a fresh copy of your code again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) module to compare the schemas defined by your currently installed modules to what is actually in your database.

With this module you will be able to identify:

1. Extras: Tables that are not present in the schema. This indicates previously installed modules that are disabled but not un-installed or modules that do not use the Schema API.
2. Mismatches: Tables for which the schema and database are different.
3. Missing: Tables in the schema that are not present in the database.

Please note that Schema requires MySQL 5.